# Cmake version update

Tags: installation, cmake

1. I am using trying to install a newer version (2.8.11) of Cmake on my linux machine. The version already installed is 2.8.6. Now I build the newer version with **cmake** command in a separate ***mycmakebuild*** folder. then i run **make** command. according to the cmake website, if i run **cmake** from my build folder***mycmakebuild*** , **make install** command is optional. Which means after running **cmake** and **make** commands, i do not need to run **make install**. But when I check the version of cmake in ***mycmakebuild*** folder using **cmake --version**, it still shows the older version. (I do not have admin privilege to run **make install** command). please suggest what could be wrong.
2. What if I want to run cmake command outside of ***mycmakebuild*** folder? It still runs the older version. How to give it the path to run cmake from the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like you just call the newly built executable the wrong way. After you change directory to where the executalbe is, you call it with

```
./cmake
```

instead of only

```
cmake
```

The first calls the executable inside the current directory, the latter the one found in the systems search path ($PATH).

If you like to call your cmake-Version from anotherplace, just prepend the path to it, something like

```
mycmakebuild/src/cmake
```

As for the **make install**: you can do it, you just have to adjust the path to where the files should go. If you run **make edit_cache** inside your build-directory, you can set the **CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX** to e.g. /home/yourlogin/cmake and cmake will install to that location. Using this, you can also get rid of the many (useless) object files inside the build directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have installed using bootstrap and now i Can see the updated version running.